# PHP-Encrypting login Credentials Accessing API

Tags: php, api, hash, authentication

I am trying to call the Harvest API. But,in order to do that the username and password has to be put in the PHP file. Now, I have security concerns, I don't want to directly put my login credentials in a file. I have read about hashing mechanisms like SHA1, md5. Would that be applicable to my situation? Because most of the examples I am looking right now are based on verifying login credentials. Here, I need a way to hide my login credentials so it is not exposed publicly. Kindly suggest a way to go about this.

```
$user= //Actual username;
$password= //Actual Password
$harvest_user = $user; // Harvest username, usually an email address
$harvest_pass = $password; //  Harvest password
$harvest_account = $account;

require_once 'HarvestAPI.php';

spl_autoload_register(array('HarvestAPI', 'autoload') );

$harvestAPI = new HarvestAPI();
$harvestAPI->setUser($harvest_user);
$harvestAPI->setPassword($harvest_pass);
$harvestAPI->setAccount($harvest_account);

$result = $harvestAPI->getUsers();
// If Harvest returns successful
if ($result->code == 200) {
  $people = $result->data;
}
else{
echo "Not Successful";
}
?>
```

Comment: both sha1 and MD5 are no longer considered safe to use as password hashing/storage

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `md5()` Method.

Just encrypt the password after the registration and store ist in a database or where else you are storing the login information.

At the login just encrypt the typed password an check if its the same like the one in your database.

Nobody can get the password from the database because the `md5()` Method isn't 
reversible.

Encrypt like that: `$pw2store = md5($password);`

Or replace the password with the encrypted one: `$password = md5($password);`

Hoped I could help.

Comment: ever heard of Rainbow tables?

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: It's my downvote. I did that because the recommendation is bad.

Comment: *"Roger that" Sam!* @JayBlanchard

Comment: *"10-4 Ralph."* @Fred-ii-

Comment: I see you *got yer ears on* there Sam! @JayBlanchard

Comment: sorry but i've only used mysql database until yet and i think I will use it forever it works good. So yes I've never heard of Rainbow tables.

Comment: [Rainbow Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) aren't what you think they are.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have a form for which I would like to submit the Information by the submit button  and access the API. I cannot have a login form to put the login credentials and at the same time the username and password cannot be stored in the file itself. Kindly suggest how it can be encrypted. Does one need a database to store the login Information?

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!defined('access')): die('no access for you');

class HarvestAPI
{
    private $username;
    private $...;

    public function __construct($u,$...)
    {
        $this->username = $u;
    }

    public function start()
    {
        require_once 'HarvestAPI.php';
        spl_autoload_register(array('HarvestAPI', 'autoload') );
        $harvestAPI = new HarvestAPI();
        $harvestAPI->setUser($this->username);
        $harvestAPI->setPassword($....);
        $harvestAPI->setAccount($....);

        return $harvestAPI->getUsers();
    }
}
```

**Usage (in another file):**

```
define('access',0);
require_once 'thatfileabove.php';
$result = (new HarvestAPI('username','ect..'))->start();
($result->code == 200)? $people = $result->data : "Not Successful";
```

Unless someone looks at your code, its impossible now for them to see your credentials.